# White-space problem using Picker/Dropdown in React Native

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I have some problems using Dropdown/ Picker in React Native. At first, I thought it was the library issue but many times trying different libraries, the problem stood still. When i clicked the dropdown or picker there a white space between the input above and dropdown below, here an example:

[image]

Other thing work well but this problem. The device i'm using is Android. When using Expo web browser everything is fine.In advanced, i'm using https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-element-dropdown

Here my code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.labelStyle, { color: "black", fontSize: 16 }]}>
          Điểm đi
        </Text>
        <Dropdown
          style={[styles.dropdown, isFocusDi && { borderColor: "blue" }]}
          placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
          selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
          iconStyle={styles.iconStyle}
          data={dataDi}
          maxHeight={200}
          labelField="label"
          valueField="value"
          placeholder={!isFocusDi ? "Chọn nơi chuyển hàng đến" : "..."}
          value={valueDi}
          onFocus={() => setIsFocusDi(true)}
          onBlur={() => setIsFocusDi(false)}
          onChange={(item) => {
            setValueDi(item.value);
            setIsFocusDi(false);
          }}
          renderLeftIcon={() => (
            <AntDesign
              style={styles.icon}
              color={isFocusDi ? "blue" : "black"}
              name="Safety"
              size={20}
            />
          )}
        />
      </View>
      <Button
        title="test function"
        onPress={() => console.log(valueKho, valueDi)}
      >
</Button>
```

style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 16,
  },
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
  icon: {
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  placeholderStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  selectedTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  iconStyle: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  inputSearchStyle: {
    height: 40,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  labelStyle: {
    paddingVertical: 5,
    fontWeight: "700",
  },
});
```

I updated the TabBar navigation in case it

```
<Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "#e91e63",
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Đặt hàng"
          component={Order}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Đặt hàng",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="cart-plus"
                size={size}
                color={color}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Xuất hàng"
          component={ExportPlan}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Xuất hàng",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="cart-minus"
                size={size}
                color={color}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Kho"
          component={KhoQuanly}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Kho",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <FontAwesome5 name="warehouse" size={size} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen
          name="Thống kê"
          component={ThongKeQuanLy}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Thống kê",
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <AntDesign name="barschart" size={size} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code?

Comment: I'll update above.

Comment: It happens with every single select/dropdown library

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occur when the StatusBar is translucent
to solve this problem add
statusBarIsTranslucent={true}

Answer (score 1):

For react-native-select-dropdown.
statusBarTranslucent={true}

https://github.com/AdelRedaa97/react-native-select-dropdown#statusbartranslucent

Comment: Hi, congratz on your first answer! Please consider formatting/wrapping code snippets for best results. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more information